# Remove the expiry date of the android game app within lib.so files

Tags: android, lib

I have downloaded a modded android game here from the telegram group, but it has an expiration date, the modder of the game just gives us the lib.so file to compile when it reaches the expiration date to be able to open again.

I want to edit that lib.so file to remove the expiration date, how can I do that?

Comment: You're basically asking us to teach you how to do reverse engineering.  That's way too large a topic for an SO question

Comment: Sorry this is my first time, thanks anyway